# .HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase is not working in .net core 2.1?

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.1

We are using the code below to send the custom message from server side to client side in HTTP request. It is working properly in `.NET Core 2.0`

```
Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase
```

While using the same code in `.NET Core 2.1` it does not work. It doesn't throw any script errors but we couldn't get message in client side success.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: I've tested it with Postman and it returns the correct `ReasonPhrase`. Maybe your client side is reading the value incorrectly?

Comment: I get could not get any response in Postman.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it answers your question:

> This is not caused by any code changes in the framework, it's caused
> by a project configuration change.
>
> The 2.0 project templates did not have HTTPS enabled by default, the
> 2.1 templates do. When using HTTP the browser uses HTTP/1.1 and ReasonPhrase works as expected. When using HTTPS the browser uses
> HTTP/2 and ReasonPhrase no longer works.

Full answer by Chris Ross [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2240#issuecomment-457331868).